# #include <string.h> -> Abort trap: 6?

Tags: c, include, string.h

I'm learning programming in c, and I'm running into some weirdness.

I was messing around with char arrays/strings and using different functions. So I have this program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char a[] = {'H','e','y','a','\0'};
    strcat(a,"bro!");
    printf(a);
}

$ gcc -o test.o test.c -Wall
$ ./test.o
Heya bro!
$
```

works as expected, but if I add

```
#include <string.h>
```

to the beginning, then I get this

```
$ gcc -o test.o test.c -Wall
$ ./test.o
Abort: trap 6
$
```

Comment: It's aconventional to call your executable with a `.o` extension; that's used for object files, normally, not complete programs.  Your original code doesn't  compile cleanly under C99 or C11 rules.  Your `strcat()` call invokes undefined behaviour; you write beyond the end of your array.  With UB, anything is allowed — crashes, appearing to work, reformatting your hard drive.

Comment: Undefined behavior you are blowing out the back of your `char a[]` and you unluckily got your desired result the first time. Make `a` big enough to fit the concatenated string array.

Comment: I was surprised by the two different behaviors (I know UB is UB) but most of the time things are deterministic. If you don't include `string.h` the compiler emits a call to `strcat`. But if you include the header, it may happen, and it is the case here, that the emitted call is something else than vanilla `strcat`. On my machine it calls `__strcat_chk` which behave differently and produces an abort.

Answer (score 3):

The `strcat` tries to append characters but again the size of the array is not big enough to hold them giving you [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).(Here in your case undefined behavior results in the error you saw - it could have been the case that everything worked also.) Because `strcat` tried to write beyond the array `a`. And the first parameter of `printf` should be a format specifier like `printf("%s",a);`.

```
char a[] = {'H','e','y','a','\0'};
```

Here `a` has 5 elements. The size of the array is `5`. You need to take a bigger array.

```
char a[9] = {'H','e','y','a','\0'};
```

If you had make the array to hold 9 characters then it would have worked.

Comment: oh, so strcat() doesn't provide extra space for the characters you are appending. I'm still confused why it worked when I didn't include string.h

Comment: That was just bad luck. Appreciate when such buggy routines don't work, because they are a pain in the ass to find once your project is larger and weird stuff is happening o.O

Comment: @PaulMyers by aware that `strcat` doesn't "provide" anything, it just appends a string to another existing string, not more and not less. If there is not enough memory you're out of luck. It's up to _you_ to ensure that there is enough memory.

Answer (score 3):

When you initialize an array and omit the dimension, the compiler infers the dimension from the number of initializers.
So, this statement:

```
char a[] = {'H','e','y','a','\0'};
```

is equivalent to this:

```
char a[5] = {'H','e','y','a','\0'};
```

The `strcat()` appends a copy of source string to the destination string. It does not check whether the destination buffer is large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string or not. If the destination is not large enough to hold the concatenated resulting string then it leads to undefined behavior which includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may do exactly what the programmer intended.

You should specify the size of buffer `a` enough big to hold the concatenated resulting string. In your program, source string `bro!` size is `4`. The `strcat()` overwrites the destination `null` character with the first character of source string while concatenating them and a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed. So, in your case the minimum size required to hold the concatenated resulting string is `9`.

Declare `a` as:

```
char a[9] = {'H','e','y','a','\0'};
```

should work fine.

As David suggested (in comments) instead of `9`, you can take some reasonable size of buffer like `512` or `1024` (for e.g. `a[512]` or `a[1024]`).
It helps you to avoid problems up to some extent. However, you need to take care of the buffer overflow problems in your code. For e.g., you can use [strncat()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat) which gives you the flexibility of specifying the max size you can append in the destination string.
You can specify maximum number of characters to be appended as -

```
(size of destination buffer) - (the length of the destination string) - 1
```

to avoid the buffer overflow.

Comment: `char a[9]` will work for the current purpose, but memory is cheap. Why not suggest a reasonably sized allocation that would allow for more flexibility? You can't resize an array after the fact.

Comment: @DavidBowling: In my answer, I have mentioned - _"in your case the minimum size required to hold the concatenated resulting string is 9"_.

Comment: Yes, I did see that. It is common to see, especially with learners, minimum sizes used in arrays; but this can lead to trouble, and there is no reason to be stingy. I routinely use `char buffer[1024]` or `char buffer[4096]` with user input buffers. There is no penalty for this, and it helps avoid certain types of I/O troubles. I find that it is good to remind learners that it is OK to allocate generously, and that it is better to think about reasonable expectations than minimum needs.